# How to send a php email with authentication

Tags: php

My ISP has started requiring SMTP authentication and I seem not to be able to figure out how to add the said information to my header. Below is a simplified version of my code. Any help will be very much  appreciated.

Thank  You.

```
<?php
$content = 'Hello';
$content .= ' 123';

$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ABC <user@domain1.com>';

// The four lines below need to be fixed.
$smtpinfo["host"] = "host.hostingcompany.com";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = "username";
$smtpinfo["password"] = "password";

$sent = 'user1@domain2.com', 'A test email', $content, $headers);
$sent = 'user2@domain2.com', 'A test email', $content, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a third party library which supports SMTP authentication like [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) [(download)](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

E.g. Usage:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = "Your<br>HTML Message";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? Can it be done without adding the phpmailer? Thank You.

Comment: Here's another way... http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm